# Prove that $d(x+y, \mathcal{K}) \leq d(x, \mathcal{K})+d(y, \mathcal{K})$ for all $ x, y \in \mathcal{H}$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C},$ and let $\mathcal{K}$ be a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}.$

Prove that $d(x+y, \mathcal{K}) \leq d(x, \mathcal{K})+d(y, \mathcal{K}) \forall  x, y \in \mathcal{H}$

We have that there exists a unique vector in $\mathcal{K}$ that minimizes the distances between $x+y$ and $\mathcal{K},$ call that $a+b.$

There exists a sequence $a_n+b_n$ that satisfies the following,
\begin{align} d(x+y,\mathcal{K}) &\leq \| (x+y) - (a_n+b_n) \| \\
&\leq \| x - a_n \| + \| y-b_n \| \\
&< d(x,\mathcal{K}) + \frac{1}{n} + d(y,\mathcal{K}) + \frac{1}{n}.\end{align} Then taking $n \rightarrow \infty, $ we have the desired inequality $d(x+y, \mathcal{K}) \leq d(x, \mathcal{K})+d(y, \mathcal{K}).$

Does this proof look correct, or close to correct? I could not find a similar question already posted.

Comment: Where did you pluck $a,b$ from? Certainly there is some element $k \in K$ that is nearest $x+y$, but how did you separate $k$ into $a+b$? Do you mean a linear subspace?

Comment: I used a+b rather than a single vector so I could utilize triangle inequality. Is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: Unless you specify how you separate the vector into $a,b$ it is meaningless. Also, where did the $a_n,b_n$ come from? You haven't used the fact that ${\cal K}$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $d_K(x) = \|x-a\|, d_K(y)= \|y-b\|$.
Then $a+b \in K$ and so $d_K(x+y) \le \|x+y-(a+b)\| \le \|x-a\| + \|y-b\| = d_K(x)+d_K(y)$.

This is true whether or not $K$ is closed, you just need to refine the argument slightly.

It is straightforward to show that $d_K(tx) = |t| d_K(x)$ and since $K$ is closed, $d_K(x) = 0 $ **iff** $x \in K$.

Hence we can use $d_K$ to define a norm on $H / K$ (that is the quotient space where $x \sim y$ **iff** $x-y \in K$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. As $d(x,K)=\inf_{k\in K}d(x, k)$, there is a unique $a\in K$ such that
$$\|x - a\|= d(x, a) < d(x, K) + \epsilon$$.
Similarly, there is a unique $b\in K$ such that
$$\|y - b\| = d(y, b) < d(y, K) + \epsilon.$$
Since $K$ is a subspace of $H$, $a + b\in K$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
d(x+y, K)&\leq d(x+y, k_x + k_y)\\
&= \|(x+y) - (k_x+k_y)\|\\
&= \|(x - k_x) + (y - k_y)\|\\
&\leq \|x - a\| + \|y - b\|\\
&= d(x, a) + d(y, b)\\ 
&< d(x, K) + d(y, K) + 2\epsilon.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, we must have
$$
d(x+y, K)\leq  d(x, K) + d(y, K).
$$

Comment: If $K$ is convex and closed, there is a unique minimiser.